# How to remove unnecessary spacing in flalign ?

Tags: pdftex, align

When I try to write the following list of equations, I get too much spacing between certain elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{flalign*}
        \Rightarrow & \quad 1-p(1+\beta) \quad & \geq & \quad\frac{c+u}{W} &\\
        \Rightarrow & \quad (1+\beta) & \leq & \quad\frac{1}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} &\\
        \Rightarrow & \quad \beta & \leq & \quad\frac{1-p}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} & \\
        \Rightarrow & \quad \beta_{max} & = & \quad \frac{1-p}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} &
    \end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Whatever I try I can't remove the unnecessary spacing before the inequality sign.[image]

Comment: Why do you add all those `\quad`s? Isn't the default spacing enough?

Comment: I thought it looked better. However the problem is not there. With or without those `\quad` the problem remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot that when there are k columns of alignment, you need 2k-1 `&`: one for the new column (exceptthe first), and one for the alignment point in this column.

Here are two suggestions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{flalign*}
        & \Rightarrow & 1-p(1+\beta) & \geq\frac{c+u}{W} &\\
         & \Rightarrow & (1+\beta) & \leq \frac{1}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} &\\
         & \Rightarrow & \beta & \leq \frac{1-p}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} & \\
         & \Rightarrow & \beta_{\max} & = \frac{1-p}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} &
    \end{flalign*}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        & \Rightarrow & \qquad 1-p(1+\beta) & \geq\frac{c+u}{W}\\
         & \Rightarrow & (1+\beta) & \leq\frac{1}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} \\
         & \Rightarrow & \beta & \leq \frac{1-p}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} \\
         & \Rightarrow & \beta_{\max} & =  \frac{1-p}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp}
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Addendum:*

If you want the block of equations to be aligned on the left, you can use the `fleqn` option from `amsmath` (in which case all equations will be left-aligned. If you want only  *some* equations to be left-aligned, you can nest athe `alignat*` environment in a `fleqn` environment (from package `nccmath`). The environment can take an optional argument, which is the distance from the left margin (0pt by default).

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[1em]
        \begin{alignat*}{2}
            & \Rightarrow & \quad 1-p(1+\beta ) & \geq\frac{c+u}{W}\\
             & \Rightarrow & (1+\beta ) & \leq\frac{1}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} \\
             & \Rightarrow & \beta & \leq \frac{1-p}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp} \\
             & \Rightarrow & \beta_{\max} & = \frac{1-p}{p}-\frac{c+u}{Wp}
        \end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking for something with the `flalign*` command like the first one you suggested. However, I don't want the huge spacing that you got between the `\Rightarrow` and the rest of the equation... I just need to move the right part of the equation much closer to the left one. The left one should remain aligned left.

Comment: I give you a +1 for the **k** columns explanation. However I can't accept the answer as it is since it does not solve my issue. I will validate it if you can show me a solution that allows to align everything to the left without the huge spacing that you get in your first solution.

Comment: Oh! I didn't understand you wanted everything on the left. I suppose you don't want *all* your equations aligned to the left?

Comment: @YohanObadia: I've updated my answer with another example. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes exactly ! This is not achievable with `flalign` ? Meanwhile I will use your solution, thanks !

Comment: It can't be done with flalign (at least in a simple way), because  flalign defines three columns for alignments, and the set the three columns spread across the whole text width. In my opinion it's the simplest  solution: it amounts to allow locally the `fleqn` option. Furthermore, `nccmath` has very interesting and useful medium-size commands and environments (between displaystyle and scriptstyle).